# Using Nexted for loop to iterate through all cells in a worksheet and all worksheets in a workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to update record on all worksheets in a workbook.
My search values are in column No 6 and the replace values are in column No 9

The code is only working for a worksheet not the entire worksheet at a time.

I tried this below but it is giving me an error

```
Sub AllWorksheetsLoop()
    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim I As Integer
    ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
    ' workbook.
    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count

    ' Begin the loop.
    For I = 1 To WS_Count
        Dim N As Long
        Dim count As Long

        N = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For count = 1 To N
            v1 = Cells(count, 6).Value
            If v1 = "Palm Tree (M)" Then Cells(count, 9).Value = "='Project Comp Rate Akwa Ibom'!K7"
        Next count
    Next I
End Sub
```

Kindly assists pls

Comment: Why would you ever want to select all the cells in the workbook? Also, what is the error and on which line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like, search column F of each worksheet for `"Palm Tree (M)"`; if found, enter the stated formula in the cell, on the same row, 3 columns to the right. I assume that you exclude the sheet referenced in the formula from being searched.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub FindThatPhrase()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim ws As Worksheet, found As Range
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Project Comp Rate Akwa Ibom" Then
            Set found = GetAllMatches("Palm Tree (M)", ws.Columns("F"))
            If Not found Is Nothing Then
                Debug.Print ws.Name, found.Address
                found.Offset(, 3) = "='Project Comp Rate Akwa Ibom'!$K$7"
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Function GetAllMatches(ByVal findString As String, ByVal searchRng As Range) As Range

    Dim foundCell As Range
    Dim gatheredRange As Range

    With searchRng

        Set foundCell = searchRng.Find(findString)
        Set gatheredRange = foundCell

        Dim currMatch As Long

        For currMatch = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, findString)

            Set foundCell = .Find(What:=findString, After:=foundCell, _
                                  LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                  SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

            If Not gatheredRange Is Nothing Then
                Set gatheredRange = Union(gatheredRange, foundCell)
            Else
                Set gatheredRange = foundCell
            End If

        Next currMatch

    End With

    Set GetAllMatches = gatheredRange

End Function
```

Comment: That is the exact thing I have been trying for all day but not working. I just tried the code and It seems not to work yet.

Comment: Exactly as above? As works for me. What does not working mean for you?

Comment: please why use <> not I guess  if I am not wrong instead of = in the this part on the code  If ws.Name <> "Project Comp Rate Akwa Ibom"

Comment: you want to ignore the sheet called Project Comp Rate Akwa Ibom when doing you search don't you? You want the other sheets to refer to Project Comp Rate Akwa Ibom if the value is found their column 6.

Comment: I understand the code now, I expect it to work but it is not. I am using Microsoft excel 2016

Comment: You have a perfect understanding of what I am battling with but just that it is not working yet.

Comment: What does not working mean? Any error messages? Also, have you checked that Palm Tree (M) is present? Spelt the same way? No white space or hidden characters also in the cell?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176376/discussion-between-edwinfad-and-qharr).